# Android overriding newView() and bindView() issue

Tags: android, android-listview, simplecursoradapter, android-cursor

Here's my custom simple cursor adapter:

```
public MySimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, 
        int[] to, int flags) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to, 0);
    this.mContext = context;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor c) {

    TextView rowView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.row);
    ImageView rowImg = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img);

    String img = null;
    String row = null;

    if (c != null) {
        img = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Db.TABLE_IMG));
        row = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Db.TABLE_TITLE));
    }

    if (img != null) rowImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.smiley);
    else img.setImageResource(0);

    rowView.setText(row);

}
```

---

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    String[] from = new String[] { ... };
    int[] to = new int[] { ... };
            ... 
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);

    mAdapter = new MySimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, null, from,
            to, 0);
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);


public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    String[] projection = { Db.TABLE_ID,
            Db.TABLE_TITLE };

    CursorLoader c = new CursorLoader(this,
            MyProvider.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);
    return c;
}

public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    mAdapter.swapCursor(data);
}

public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
}
```

Error when populating the ListView:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.

Comment: Why are you querying your content provider at every row? That's horribly inefficient. You should be querying ONCE on your main URI to retrieve a list of all of your data items. Notice how your adapter takes a cursor in the constructor? that is intended so you perform your one query and pass in the cursor. Then the adapter manages your cursor for you

Comment: I understand. Where should this query be made ?

Comment: before you create your adapter in your activity.. something like  Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(MyProvider.CONTENT_URI, new String[] { Db.TABLE_IMG, Db.TABLE_TITLE }, null, null, null);
 MySimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new  MySimpleCursorAdapter(layout, c, from, to, flags);
 obviously replace the variables in the constructor with the ones you are using since i just put in placeholders

Comment: I'm using Loaders and I'm doing this in onCreateLoader. When instantiating the custom cursoradapter in onCreate() I pass null since the cursor is not ready. Does this mean I'm querying for the data twice with the code I posted?

Comment: "I'm using Loaders and I'm doing this in onCreateLoader" -- your `bindView()` method calls `query()`. `bindView()` is not `onCreateLoader()`. "Does this mean I'm querying for the data twice with the code I posted?" -- probably many more times than twice.

Comment: I'm confused and I can't find a single example on the web using a `Loader` with a custom `CursorAdapter`. I can't use the cursor passed to `bindView()` because it's giving me an error saying the cursor is not initialized correctly. I know how to do it the way @dymmeh is saying but that's using a `startManagingCursor()` method which is deprecated.

Comment: @Mark in your onLoadFinished method you should be calling  'adapter.swapCursor(cursor);' where 'cursor' is the new cursor that is returned to you when the load completes. If using a cursorloader you should initialize your adapter in the onCreate method of your activity by passing in a null Cursor. Once the loader finishes you swap in the newly loaded cursor and your adapter will do the rest for you. Take a look at an example here: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_loading-data_cursorloader/

Comment: @dymmeh I'm doing exactly that. I posted the code as well.

Comment: Everything looks fine. I'd put your initLoader code below your creation of the adapter (im not sure if this can happen, but  initloader may finish before creating the adapter leading to a nullpointerexception). Did you remove all of the code that was associated with creating a new cursor in your adapter? ex.  int id = cursor.getColumnIndex(Db.TABLE_ID); Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(...; c.moveToFirst(); c.close(); ??  the only code you should have should be fetching values from your cursor

Comment: @dymmeh I updated the code with the error I'm now getting. I initially had the initLoader call below the adapter but I thought that might be the issue so I tested by moving it above. It didn't help.

Comment: @CommonsWare have you got any idea why I'm getting that error ?

Comment: Your projection { Db.TABLE_ID, Db.TABLE_TITLE } differs from the values you are trying to retrieve Db.TABLE_IMG and Db.TABLE_TITLE. Since you aren't querying for Db.TABLE_IMG when you try to retrieve it it doesn't exist (which throws the error). Change your projection to include Db.TABLE_IMG and that error should go away

Comment: @dymmeh That was it, thank you so much. If you want you can add it as a reply so I can accept the answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Your projection { Db.TABLE_ID, Db.TABLE_TITLE } differs from the values you are trying to retrieve Db.TABLE_IMG and Db.TABLE_TITLE. Since you aren't querying for Db.TABLE_IMG when you try to access it through your adapter it will not exist (which throws the error). Change your projection to include Db.TABLE_IMG and that error should go away